# Save text in plist file with specific date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to store some stings into a plist file, the saving process works fine, but these notes should be saved based on a specific date, for example I enter a note on 2 Feb then I need enter another note on 5 Feb, and when I move during these dates my notes should show on these dates. I would be grateful if you help me.

Here is my code:

```
//Save Setting ///////////////////
- (NSString *) saveFilePath
{
    NSArray *pathArray =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

    return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"note.plist"];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:saveTextToday.text ,nil];
    [values writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
    [values release];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    ////Save Setting /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    NSString *myPath = [self saveFilePath];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];

    if (fileExists)
    {
        NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
        saveTextToday.text = [values objectAtIndex:0];
        [values release];
    }

    // notification
    UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    // add yourself to the dispatch table 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) 
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification 
                                               object:myApp];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're saving an array to a file, but using a ".plist" file extension.  While the file created will be a plist file, there is no date information in the content.

Instead of an array, you could use an NSDictionary.  Use the current date as the key, and the array you're using now as the object.  Like this:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
 NSString *todayKey = [self showPersianFullDate]; // or [self showPersianFullDate:[NSDate date]]
 [myDictionary setObject:saveTextToday.text forKey:todayKey];
 [myDictionary writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Actually, the `writeToFile:atomically:` method of `NSArray` _will_ result in a plist.

Comment: @omz - thanks, you're right, I'll update my answer.  What I meant was that his structure (even though it's a plist) would have any association between the date and the data for that date.  Note that his "date" variable is not even used in the saveFilePath method, nor is any NSDate used inside the array.

Comment: would you please review my question ?

Comment: Your method "showPersianFullDate" would be even more useful if it took an NSDate as a parameter.  Then you could use it to generate the keys for your dictionary.  I updated my code above to use the dictionary with the persian date key.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is use the NSFileManager to find out when the file was saved, like this:

```
NSString *path = @"the path you've saved you plist to";
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDate *creationDate = nil;

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
{   
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error];
    creationDate = [attributes objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];
}
```

creationDate now contains the date when the file was first saved. To get the date when it was *last* saved, use NSFileModificationDate instead.

Comment: The same place where you load your array from the plist file, in your viewDidLoad (in fact I see you're using NSFileManager in there already, so you can merge my if (...existsAtPath) clause with your own if (fileExists) code.

Comment: thanks but your code works as same as mine , I create a custom calendar app which user can write their notes in it , for example in 3 Feb user writes something and this text should be saved in 3 Feb , and when user move to the another days he/she could write something else accruing to thad day date

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. This is a much more complex problem. You need to create a data structure of strings keyed by date. You could so this using an NSDictionary instead of an NSArray (you can save and load dictionaries as plists too) where the key is a date string like @"2012/11/02" and the object is your text.